# Tired by waiting

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions

> If you can wait and not be tired by waiting

Why Rudyard Kipling used the preposition "by"instead of "of"? What the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This from Kipling's poem *If*:

> If you can wait and not be tired by waiting,
>   Or being lied about, don’t deal in lies,

*Tired by waiting* means exhaustion caused by waiting.  *Tired of waiting* means to have lost patience because of the wait.